# Ethernet Card Drivers in Linux-Libre kernel

Tags: drivers, ethernet, linux-kernel

I recently installed both Hyperbola and Arch and became thorough with installation process. Didn't like them. Installed parabola linux.

When I finally boot into my fresh install,

```
ip link
```

doesn't return my ethernet card which used to be at enp2. I want to connect it to internet and update it.

```
lspci -v
```

shows realtek card kernel module not loaded. It is r8169 (or some number)

```
modprobe r8169
```

gives module not in kernel error. Please help.

Edit 1:
lsmod shows

Module Size UsedBy

xhci_pci 20480 0

ehci_pci 20480 0

I loaded RTL818x_pci yet the card didn't show up

/sys/bus/pci_express/drivers

has
aer, dpc, pcie_pme, pciehp

I can execute 'modprobe pciehp'. Others show module not found in kernel directory.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're avoiding a traditional kernel with non-free drivers included if you're going to install them anyway?

Comment: If I have to install, I will. But I prefer configuring a libre kernel. I'm okay with minimum required proprietary blobs.